# Enum bases feature toggles are over written by DB?

Tags: togglz

I have a set of feature toggles configured in an ENUM.

If I insert a value into the TOGGLZ table, i can override this flag. 
How can I block this? Is my config wrong?

```
getFlag(my_fag) == false;
insert into TOGGLZ values ('my_flag','1','null','null')
getFlag(my_fag) == true; // i expect false
```

Any one an idea?

Comment: If you want to hardcode the state, just don't use JDBCStateRepository at all.

Comment: @chkal True, but let me expend on this. Some of the features should be toggleble, but not all. I tought by defining groups this would be handled. But its not. Think i have to implement my own state repo

Comment: I don't see much sense in defining toggles which cannot be toggled. Why not using simple boolean constants in this case?

Comment: @chkal there are two sets of toggles, one can change, the other one must not. Only for development purposes we need to toggle both on demand.